# Problems with sink on flink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, data-stream

[enter image description here][1] I could do this to try first, this works well this just print the data on another topic I trie to follow the same logic but don get the result

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.connector.base.DeliveryGuarantee;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaRecordSerializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaSink;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.initializer.OffsetsInitializer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingEventTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;

import java.util.Properties;

public class DataStreamJob {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

            KafkaSource<TradeEventBase> source = KafkaSource.<TradeEventBase>builder()
                    .setBootstrapServers("redpanda-0:9092")
                    .setTopics("data")
                    .setGroupId("")
                    .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
                    .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new TradeEventDeserializationSchema())
                    .build();

            DataStream<TradeEventBase> trades = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");

            // Keying by symbol and then applying a 2-second time window
            DataStream<Tuple2<String, Long>> counts = trades
                    .keyBy(event -> event.getSymbol())  // Assuming you have a getSymbol() method in TradeEventBase
                    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(2)))
                    .aggregate(new CountAggregator());

            // Define Kafka producer properties
            Properties producerProps = new Properties();
            producerProps.put("bootstrap.servers", "redpanda-0:9092");

            KafkaSink<Tuple2<String, Long>> sink = KafkaSink.<Tuple2<String, Long>>builder()
                    .setBootstrapServers("redpanda-0:9092")
                    .setRecordSerializer(KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
                            .setTopic("resultado")
                            .setValueSerializationSchema(new Tuple2SerializationSchema())
                            .build()
                    )
                    .setDeliveryGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
                    .build();

            counts.sinkTo(sink);

            env.execute("Kafka Trade Consumer-Producer");
        }
    }
```

this is an example of what it consume from kafka

```
{
"e":"aggTrade"
"E":1692050397253
"a":1824780414
"s":"BTCUSDT"
"p":"29390.30"
"q":"0.001"
"f":4007152464
"l":4007152464
"T":1692050397097
"m":false
}
```

this is the deserialization class

```
public class TradeEventDeserializationSchema implements DeserializationSchema<TradeEventBase> {
    private transient ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public TradeEventBase deserialize(byte[] message) throws IOException {
        if (objectMapper == null) {
            objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        }

        String msg = new String(message);

        // Check the event type in the message and deserialize accordingly
        if (msg.contains("\"e\":\"aggTrade\"")) {
            return objectMapper.readValue(msg, AggTradeEvent.class);
        } else if (msg.contains("\"e\":\"trade\"")) {
            return objectMapper.readValue(msg, TradeEvent.class);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown event type in message: " + msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(TradeEventBase nextElement) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<TradeEventBase> getProducedType() {
        return TypeInformation.of(TradeEventBase.class);
    }
}
```

what Ive learned I tried to find the problem but dont see it I try with chatgpt 4, and also couldnt I dont see nothing wrong on the logs but the job dosent work even create the topic.

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.connector.base.DeliveryGuarantee;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaRecordSerializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaSink;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.initializer.OffsetsInitializer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

import java.util.Properties;

public class DataStreamJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        KafkaSource<Object> source = KafkaSource.<Object>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("redpanda-0:9092")
                .setTopics("data")
                .setGroupId("")
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new TradeEventDeserializationSchema())
                .build();

        DataStream<Object> trades = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");

        // Define Kafka producer properties
        Properties producerProps = new Properties();
        producerProps.put("bootstrap.servers", "redpanda-0:9092");

        KafkaSink<Object> sink = KafkaSink.<Object>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("redpanda-0:9092")
                .setRecordSerializer(KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
                        .setTopic("result1")
                        .setValueSerializationSchema(new TradeEventSerializationSchema())
                        .build()
                )
                .setDeliveryGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
                .build();

        trades.sinkTo(sink);

        env.execute("Kafka Trade Consumer-Producer");
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWykl.png
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". In both cases, your sink doesn't write to the console... Did you create all topics ahead of time? Also, your groupId string shouldn't be empty

Comment: I add and check quickly everthing, and I notice that on the columns that measure the data send and received, on the kafka source dont recive but they send, and for the sing they recived but dosent send, the amount dosent increase too much but there are some bytes increasing slowly continously.